# kafka and JMX-exporter

Tags: bash, apache-kafka, prometheus, jmx-exporter

I am unable to use JMX exporter to expose kafka metrics. Can you look at my steps and correct me where needed.?
I am following steps [here](https://medium.com/activewizards-machine-learning-company/kafka-monitoring-with-prometheus-telegraf-and-grafana-6228fed736f1) to enable kafka with JMX exporter.

Following are step by step instruction I followed

```
#get kafka
wget kafka_2.11-2.0.0

# Download Prometheus JMX exporter:
sudo wget -P /opt/kafka/prometheus/ https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.3.0/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar
sudo wget -P /opt/kafka/prometheus/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/master/example_configs/kafka-0-8-2.yml

#Edit Prometheus JMX exporter config file; and append following lines 
echo  “- pattern : kafka.producer<type=producer-metrics, client-id=(.+)><>(.+):\w* name: kafka_producer_$2” >> /opt/kafka/prometheus/kafka-0-8-2.yml
echo  “— pattern : kafka.consumer<type=consumer-metrics, client-id=(.+)><>(.+):\w* name: kafka_consumer_$2” >> /opt/kafka/prometheus/kafka-0-8-2.yml
echo  “— pattern : kafka.consumer<type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics, client-id=(.+)><>(.+):\w* name: kafka_consumer_$2” >> /opt/kafka/prometheus/kafka-0-8-2.yml


#start zookeeper in terminal 0
/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties


#start kafka broker in terminal 1
KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=’”-Xmx1000M -Xms1000M”’ 
KAFKA_OPTS=”-javaagent:/opt/kafka/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7071:/opt/kafka/prometheus/kafka-0–8–2.yml” 
JMX_PORT=7071
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties  


#start kafka consumer in terminal 2
KAFKA_OPTS=”-javaagent:/opt/kafka/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7072:/opt/kafka/prometheus/kafka-0–8–2.yml” 
JMX_PORT=7072
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh — bootstrap-server 0.0.0.0:9092 — topic test — from-beginning

#start kafka producer in terminal 3
KAFKA_OPTS=”-javaagent:/opt/kafka/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7073:/opt/kafka/prometheus/kafka-0–8–2.yml” 
JMX_PORT=7073
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh — broker-list 0.0.0.0:9092 — topic test
```

After above steps zookeeper and kafka is running fine.
I can type in producer terminal a message and it is received on consumer console.  However no kafka metrics is visible on Prometheus. To debug this I checked ports 7071/2/3 by

```
netstat -tlnp | grep 7071
netstat -tlnp | grep 7072
netstat -tlnp | grep 7073
```

which resulted in blank response; this means no service is using above ports. I feel like JMX exporter is not enabled correctly.

Can you help me with above issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the looks of your question, you put the variables on their own lines, while the blog has them on the same line...

e.g. This is how to start the Kafka server

`KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS='"-Xmx1000M -Xms1000M"' KAFKA_OPTS='-javaagent:/opt/kafka/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7071:/opt/kafka/prometheus/kafka-0–8–2.yml' JMX_PORT=7081 /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties`

Otherwise, you need to export the variables so the sub-process will pick them up like you did [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033823/configuring-kafka-with-jmx-exporter-centos-7), which seemed to be working fine for exposing the metrics

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS='"-Xmx1000M -Xms1000M"'
export KAFKA_OPTS='-javaagent:/opt/kafka/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7071:/opt/kafka/prometheus/kafka-0–8–2.yml'
export JMX_PORT=7081
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties
```

Note: The blog you linked to doesn't use `JMX_PORT`, but those ports cannot be the same as the exporter.

I would also suggest at least downloading a version newer than 0.3 - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/

and using the configs for Kafka 2.0 - https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/example_configs/kafka-2_0_0.yml

---

Sidenote: `netstat -tlnp | grep 707` would show you all them at once

Comment: i used 0.12.0 java agent with kafka 2.0.0 yaml but now i get "Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7071; nested exception is: 
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7071; nested exception is: 
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
"  error even-though  "lsof -i:7071" and "netstat -tlnpu | grep 70" shows nothing

Comment: Try using a different port? If lsof doesn't show anything, then I'm not sure what the issue would be

Comment: Oh. Set `JMX_PORT` to not match the agent, or just remove it... Prometheus Agent starts a web server. JMX is not over HTTP

Comment: Bingo it worked  i can see a process listening on 6071 now.

Comment: netstat -tlnpu |grep 60
tcp6       0      0 :::6071                 :::*                    LISTEN      35522/java

Comment: now i want to see all Broker metrics on Prometheus; i have got your comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033823/configuring-kafka-with-jmx-exporter-centos-7/58602767#58602767  i will work on gettin prometheous working on this node; Via docker container i am not able to see any broker metrics

Comment: Kafka docker container?

Comment: I am closing this question since i get all broker metrics on curl -s <IP>:7071 | grep -i kafka. thanks cricket I will open a new one for porting these metrics to Prometheus

Comment: can you look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58634019/jmx-exporter-and-prometheus

Answer (score 2):

thank you [cricket-007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) for your help.
I am listing steps i followed here for simplicity

```
wget -q -O /tmp/kafka.tgz https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.0.0/kafka_2.11-2.0.0.tgz
tar -xf /tmp/kafka.tgz --directory /opt/kafka --strip 1
rm -f /tmp/kafka.tgz

wget -q -O /tmp/kafka.tgz https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.0.0/kafka_2.11-2.0.0.tgz
mkdir /opt/kafka
tar -xf /tmp/kafka.tgz --directory /opt/kafka --strip 1
rm -f /tmp/kafka.tgz
sudo wget -P /opt/kafka/prometheus/ https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.12.0/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/master/example_configs/kafka-2_0_0.yml
cd kafka
export KAFKA_OPTS="-javaagent:/opt/kafka/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=7071:/opt/kafka/prometheus/kafka-2_0_0.yml"
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1000M -Xms1000M"
mv ../kafka-2_0_0.yml prometheus/
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties
netstat -tlnpu |grep 70

tcp6       0      0 :::7071                 :::*                    LISTEN      209455/java         
udp6       0      0 :::40705                :::*      

curl -s localhost_or_IP:7071 | grep -i kafka
long list of metrics will be dumped on stdout                          -
```